# ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile uses wrong json file every other time

Tags: json, .net, unit-testing, appsettings, xunit.net

I have a .Net 8.0 Unit test project. This project is part of a solution that contains the application projects as well.

As part of the test setup a ConfigurationBuilder is used.

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

When running the tests repeatedly, the configuration loads the (incorrect) appSettings.json file from the application project, next time the (correct) appSettings.json file from the test project, then again the incorrect file, then again the correct file, etc.

The application appSettings.json file does not contain a setting that is needed in the test project.

I tried several solutions to have the ConfigurationBuilder load the correct settings file all the time.

- Creating a PhysicalFileProvider, and using ConfigurationBuilder.SetFileProvider
- Creating a PhysicalFileProvider, and specifying that when calling AddJsonFile
- Using SetBaseDirectory

All of the above methods fail to solve the problem.
My question is: why is ConfigurationBuilder alternating between two appSettings.json file?
How can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several questions

Does your projects output folder same? If so can you replace your test appsettings.json with appsettings.test.json etc.

**TestProject.csproj**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.test.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**AgentTest.cs**

```
public class AgentTests : BaseTest
{
    static IConfiguration Configuration {get; set;}

    public AgentTests() : base(false)
    {

    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
       Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json").Build();

    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Can_Get_AgentById()
    {
       // Arrange

       int agentId = 350;
       IAgentRepository agentRepo = new AgentService(Configuration);

       // Act       

       var result = await agentRepo.GetAgentById(agentId);

       // Assert
     
       Assert.That(result is not null);
   }
}
```

I am able to use like this.

Let me know more details if this answer not covering your problem.

Comment: The output paths of the projects are different. I checked the source in the ConfigurationBuilder. It has a FileProvider containing the correct path. I checked that path, and the appSettings.json flie is there, and contains the correct settings. But the next time I ran the test, all settings were the same, but the actual file did contain the settings of the application project, not the settings of the test project. So the cause of the problem seems to be in copying the file from the project's source directory to the output directory (bin\Debug\net8.0\).

Comment: I can think of a few things.

Is your test environment a linux machine? If so, let's make sure that we enter the correct string when giving the absolute path. The problem of backslashes or straight slashes on linux/windows difference (Path.DirectorySeparatorChar usable).

Also, there is no problem to give the root file because the program start is from the bin/Debug/.Net8.0/ folder.

And can you test configuration builder add json extension method with '.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)'. So delete your appsettings one by one, check which one not found when you delete it.

Comment: I am running the test manually now in VisualStudio 2022 on a Windows 11 machine. The appSettings.json in the application project had CopyToOutputDirectory = CopyAlways. In the test project it was set to CopyIfNewer. I changed that to CopyAlways, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I will try your suggestion of changing the file name.

Comment: Changing the file name into appSettings.test.json seems to solve the problem. But it does not explain why the problem occured.

Comment: Cool, im pretty sure somewhere overriding your appsettings.json. Does your output folder has 2 appsettings rn?

Comment: Yes. There now is a appSettings.test.json (containing the settings for the test) and a appSettings.Development.json. That one contains settings from the application. That was probably overriding the appSettings.json from the test. But why that only happened every other run of the tests?